# Error : version node not found for symbol qt_version_tag@Qt_5.5

Tags: qt, static, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a dynamic library with a static version of Qt 5.7.0 on Ubuntu and the title is the error that appears I tried as suggested in some stackoverflow posts :
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--disable-symvers") 
in the cmakelists.txt file of the dynamic library but it throws an error.

so what I should do to fix that error?
Thanks in advance.

note: I tried building the dynamic library with the pre-installed Qt 5.7.0 on Qt creator and it build without any error.

Comment: Minor versions of qt libraries are incompatible

Comment: @AndreySemenov I built Qt 5.7.0 library as static from :                                   https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.7/5.7.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0.tar.gz.mirrorlist                                                                                                       then configured the kit in Qt creator and tried building it and that result in that error so I don't know why it say QT_5.5 also I tried building it with the same version of Qt but dynamic which came pre-installed with the Qt creator and it built successively.